# ¿Como puedo copiar varios archivos dentro de un directorio desde le terminal de Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

EL problema viene a que si tengo varios archivos dentro de un directorio en linux no consigo copiarlos todos a la vez, puedo copiar o bien el directorio entero o los ficheros uno a uno. ¿Alguien que me ayude con este problemilla?

Comment: Ya intentaste con `comando1 && comando2`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aunque este no es el foro para esto pero puedes hacerlo con

```
cp -R directorio1 directorio2
```

si lo que quieres es copiar los archivos dentro del directorio a otro directorio entonces seria esto

```
cd directorio1
cp *.* directorio2
```

si quieres copiar con todos y directorios seria

```
cp -R directorio1/* directorio2/
```

Comment: Eso lo que hace es copiar un directorio dentro de otro :(

Comment: hice una modificacion, intentalo

Comment: ¡Eso es justo lo que necesito! Al hacer *.* copiaria todos los que contengan un punto entonces funciona. En el caso de que dentro de un directorio haya mas directorios no funcionaria pero bueno para lo que quiero esta perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado esto buscando en google, espero que te funcione, yo también voy a probarlo

https://blog.desdelinux.net/como-mover-o-copiar-archivos-o-carpetas-en-linux/

Comment: Aquí también esta la respuesta, muchas gracias.